# iOS Simple game, select the answer from given data and set a score

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray

I'm trying to write a simple game based on selecting the correct answer (A B or C) from several question like a school test,  and count the correct/incorrect answers to set a score. 
I can t figure how to use an NSArray to store all the questions and correct answers and how to set a score. My only solution is to create a new View for each question but it sounds me like a bad solution. 
Any help will be truly appreciated.
Thanks

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *numPregunta;
IBOutlet UILabel *pregunta;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblRespuesta1;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblRespuesta2;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblRespuesta3;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblResultado;

IBOutlet UIButton *respuesta1;
IBOutlet UIButton *respuesta2;
IBOutlet UIButton *respuesta3;

}

-(IBAction)btnRespuesta1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnRespuesta2:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnRespuesta3:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)nextPregunta:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

numPregunta.text = @"Question 1";
pregunta.text = @"Question 1 text";
lblRespuesta1.text = @"ANSWER 1";
lblRespuesta2.text = @"ANSWER 2";
lblRespuesta3.text = @"ANSWER 3 ";


[super viewDidLoad];


}

-(IBAction)btnRespuesta1:(id)sender

{
    if(pregunta.text == @"Question 1 text")
{

    lblRespuesta1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lblResultado.text = @"False! ";
    lblResultado.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
}


-(IBAction)btnRespuesta2:(id)sender

{
    if(pregunta.text == @"Question 1 text")
    {

        lblRespuesta2.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lblResultado.text = @"False! ";
        lblResultado.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }

}

-(IBAction)btnRespuesta3:(id)sender

{
if(pregunta.text == @"Question 1 text")
{

    lblRespuesta3.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    lblResultado.text = @"Nice! ";
    lblResultado.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];



}

}    



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an array of question say questionsArray, which will contain all questions.Second create array of dictionary which will contain all options and correct result say resultArray contain at 0 index dictionary with keys Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 and result and value will contain corresponding values.Now take one global variable which will store the question number means which question it is displaying, say question0, question1..etc, which is nothing but question index in questionsArray.Say you are displaying question at index 0,then display options corresponding to that index ie 0 as follows:

```
NSString *answer1 = [[resultArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Answer1"];
NSString *answer2 = [[resultArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Answer2"];
NSString *answer3 = [[resultArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Answer3"];
```

and say correct answer is answer2, then result key will be 2.
and provide tag o each button like 1,2 and 3.
then in Button action you can check whether user has selected correct option or not as follows:

```
if(btn.tag == [[resultArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"result"])
{
   //correct answer is selected so increment score.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nuzhat for fast answer, I'll try later when back home and post results

Comment: I've found another solution using a .plist file to store all the Question and answers. If someone is interested i can post the code. Thanks anyway Nuhat

Comment: @user1447070 : Please post the answer that you are found.

Answer (score 0):

The way you choose is long process Initially you have to save all each question ,options and answer in a dictionary
and dictionary is added to array this makes simple to use.

```
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"question"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"option1"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"option2"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"option3"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"option4"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"answer"];
```

and add this to array

```
[array addObject dictionary]

pregunta.text = [[array objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:"question"];
lblRespuesta1.text = [[array objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:"option1"];
lblRespuesta2.text = [[array objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:"option2"];
lblRespuesta3.text = [[array objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:"option3"];
```

Comment: Thanks Sumanth for fast answer, I'll try later when back home and I ll post results.